# Se puede hacer que se impriman en una sola linea mas de un print en java?

Tags: java, funciones, print

Por ejemplo si tengo algo asi:

```
System.out.println(dia + " de");
Mes(mes);
System.out.println("del "+ anio);
```

y quiero que en la consola me queden en una sola linea
"16 de agosto del 2021"

Mes(mes):Utiliza un switch que imprime el mes solo y me queda algo asi

16 de

Agosto

del 2021

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes en `Mes()` puede que haya que modificar algo también ahí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo concatenando en el mismo println o con varios print sin salto de línea

- println (imprime y hace un salto de línea, como un enter)
- print (imprime sin el salto de línea)

Concatenando:

```
System.out.println(dia + " de " + mes + " del " + anio;
```

Salida: 16 de Agosto del 2021

Con varios print sin salto de línea;

```
System.out.print(dia + " de ");
System.out.print(mes);
System.out.print(" del " + anio);
```

Salida: 16 de Agosto del 2021

Comment: Gracias, era bastante simple pero no lo sabia jaja

Answer (score 3):

Puedes imprimir una sola cadena también mediante `System.out.printf()`, por ejemplo:

```
System.out.printf("%d de %s del %d", dia, Mes(mes), anio);
```

Aquí los marcadores `%d` y `%s` serán reemplazados por cada valor en el orden en que están. La `%d` significa un entero decimal y la `%s` una cadena.

Para más detalles puedes consultar el [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Ten en cuenta que si la llamada a `Mes()` ya imprime algo deberías considerar su modificación, poniéndole solamente un `return` de modo que esa impresión no afecte lo que pretendes hacer aquí.